# kubectl exec works on single commands, but I cannot enter a bash shell

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm on **macOS Catalina 10.15.4**, and I'm using **minikube v1.11.0** and **kubernetes v1.18.3**, both installed from brew. Minikube is initialized with the docker engine.

The initialization command is set up like so:

```
      containers:
        - name: database
          image: "mysql:5.6"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: 12345
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: user
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              value: password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: db
```

**I'm trying to get a bash script open for one of my running kubectl containers.** From research online, it appears that this should be the command that will open a bash window in my terminal:

`minikube kubectl exec -it --namespace=tools test-pod -- bash`

**However, when I run it, I get the following traceback:**

`Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'i' in -it See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.`

**It doesn't seem to want me using any arguments in my command.** Is there something I'm missing, or am I attempting to use a command that is deprecated?

**Note: I am able to run** `exec`, but not for opening a bash script. For example, I am able to run the following command:

`minikube kubectl exec test-pod -- ls /`

And it outputs this following:

```
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
bin
boot
dev
docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
entrypoint.sh
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

**Edit:** I have attempted the following command:

```
minikube kubectl exec --stdin --tty --namespace=tools test-pod -- sh
```

And I got the following traceback:

```
Error: unknown flag: --stdin
See 'minikube kubectl --help' for usage.
```

It seems like any flags at all, short or long, are failing, and I cannot figure out why they wouldn't be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`minikube kubectl` needs the `--` after the command when you want to use it with arguments:

```sh
$ minikube kubectl -- exec --stdin --tty --namespace=tools test-pod -- sh
```

You can also use plain `kubectl`

If would just make sure that your `~/.kube/config` is pointing to the right minikube context/cluster. Typically, any minikube command you run from the shell will cause it to change the context to your minikube cluster. i.e `minikube ssh`

Then just use `kubectl`

```sh
$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty --namespace=tools test-pod -- sh
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the solution:

With my configuration, initializing minikube with `minikube start --driver=docker` does not successfully initialize everything. I changed my driver to `virtualbox`, and minikube was able to ssh and continue without any issues.

Setup with a docker driver appears to be commonly issue-prone, as this GitHub thread shows: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332

Comment: Figured out an answer. See my answer.